# How to resample df based on one column and add the values from another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df` as follows:

```
id  dates   values  tz
1   2020-01-01 00:15:00 87.8    +01
2   2020-01-01 00:30:00 88.3    +01
3   2020-01-01 00:45:00 89.0    +01
4   2020-01-01 01:00:00 90.1    +01
5   2020-01-01 01:15:00 91.3    +01
6   2020-01-01 01:30:00 92.4    +01
7   2020-01-01 01:45:00 92.9    +01
8   2020-01-01 02:00:00 92.5    +01
9   2020-01-01 02:15:00 91.0    +01
10  2020-01-01 02:30:00 88.7    +01
11  2020-01-01 02:45:00 86.4    +01
12  2020-01-01 03:00:00 84.7    +01
```

What I would like to do is to club every 4 rows based on the `id` column and then add the values in the `values` column and assign it to the `dates` value when the timestamp in minutes is `00`

Example:

```
id  dates   values  tz
1   2020-01-01 00:15:00 87.8    +01
2   2020-01-01 00:30:00 88.3    +01
3   2020-01-01 00:45:00 89.0    +01
4   2020-01-01 01:00:00 90.1    +01
```

When I club the first 4 values, the output should be as follows:

```
id  dates   values  tz
1   2020-01-01 01:00:00 355.2   +01 <--- (87.8+88.3+89.0+90.1 = 355.2)
```

and similarly for the other rows as well..

The desired output:

```
id  dates   values  tz
1   2020-01-01 01:00:00 355.2   +01 <--- (87.8+88.3+89.0+90.1 = 355.2)
2   2020-01-01 02:00:00 369.1   +01 <--- (91.3+92.4+92.9+91.0 = 369.1)
3   2020-01-01 03:00:00 350.8   +01 <--- (91.0+88.7+86.4+84.7 = 350.8)
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here is possible aggregate by each `4` rows with `np.arange` by length of `DataFrame` with aggregate `sum` with `last` values per groups by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 4).agg({'dates':'last','values':'sum', 'tz':'last'})
print (df)
                dates  values  tz
0 2020-01-01 01:00:00   355.2   1
1 2020-01-01 02:00:00   369.1   1
2 2020-01-01 03:00:00   350.8   1
```